# All borders are not displaying on table in ie7 compatible view

Tags: css, internet-explorer, border, css-tables

No sure why the borders are not displaying correctly.  I tried:

```
/* ------ global ------ */

body {
margin: 0 auto;
padding:0 0;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
text-align:center;
color:#000;
}


/* ------ Content Wrapper ------ */
#wrapper {
margin: 0 auto;
width:760px;
text-align:left;
}

#content table {
font-size:.8em;
border-collapse:collapse;
text-align:left;
width:100%;
}

  #content table td {
border:solid 1px black;
 }
```

Do I need to list all the CSS border properties to get the borders on the whole table, like this:

```
border-top: 1px solid #000;
border-right: 1px solid #000;
border-bottom: 1px solid #000;
border-left: 1px solid #000;
or more ......
```

I haven't done this yet, but I have had to do this in the past with some tables to get the borders on all sides for lte IE7.  It was just as a last resort since I didn't know what else to do.

Comment: Does zooming the page make a difference?

Comment: Thanks, Mouse Food.  No, zooming is not important.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the [following jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nGPyM), which works correctly in IE7 by showing a **1 pixel solid black border** on table cells.

[image: IE7 Screenshot of jsFiddle]

I didn't change any of your code, but added a rule to include borders on table header cells `table th` as well as table data cells `table td`.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="content">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col">Column</th>
            <th scope="col">Column</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Cell</td>
            <td>Cell</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#content table {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
}

#content table th,
#content table td {
    border: solid 1px black;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}
```

If your table cells still aren't showing any borders, you might have one or more rules in your stylesheet that appear later — or have more [CSS Specificity](http://css-tricks.com/855-specifics-on-css-specificity) — that are overriding your styles.

Answer (score 0):

Try using border-collapse:separate for IE7 like this:

```
#content table {
font-size:.8em;
border-collapse:collapse;
text-align:left;
width:100%;
*border-collapse:separate;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

apply border-collapse: collapse to the table, it should fix it :)

Comment: I think the original question had border-collapse: collapse and it didn't work.  Not sure if you tested your answer or are just guessing, but you really need to test before posting, and that means opening it in IE and setting it to IE 7 compatibility mode, as per the original question.  If  you did that, then comment that you couldn't duplicate the original problem.  If not, then you may want to delete your answer before you get more downvotes.

Comment: i had the very same problem developing something similar for docmode ie7- ie8. 

Stopping myself and reading that code i assume u got to apply border to the <table> element to actually make border-collapse to collapse.

if u dont want to apply border to the table, just aim correctly>> #content table * << or >> #content table td to collapse